# How do I contribute to API development?

Tags: api

I am a CiviCRM user.  I am the informal technical support behind a CiviCRM member and the reason that they are a member (Florida Native Plant Society).

I seem to have a continual battle with limitations in the API.  I would like to know how I can interact with the people involved in development of the API.

I cannot claim to be a CiviCRM coding expert, but I am php fluent and MySQL fluent.  I think my experience with APIs (DonorPerfect and home brew, and getting around the CiviCRM api weirdnesses) might be useful to improving the CiviCRM api.

Shirley Denton
Communications Chair,
Florida Native Plant Society

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you sign up for an account with civicrm.org and hence on chat.civicrm.org (unless the latter can be done without the former) and then join the API channel there. Am sure they will love to hear from you. I understand having a tolerance for jokes about 'warm beer' can be helpful.